# Chemical potential from entropy

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy, chemical-potential

For the internal energy we have the following equation:

dU= TdS -pdV + $\mu$dN.

Now for the derivation of the entropy w.r.t the particle number we have:

$\frac {\partial S}{\partial N}=\frac {\partial S}{\partial E} \frac {\partial E}{\partial N}= \frac {\mu} T $. This would be my result.

But in my book it is with a minus: $- \frac {\mu} T$ .

Where does the minus come from?

Comment: You can see where it comes from by setting dU and dV equal to zero in your starting equation.

Comment: Yes, but if you follow the above derivation which I wrote (and I hope it is not wrong) then you do not get the minus. Normally if the minus is there, then it should be in both cases, or no? What is my mistake, this is what i am asking

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Careful practitioners always include the conditions of partial differentiation. If instead of writing

$$\frac{\partial S}{\partial N}=\frac{\partial S}{\partial E}\frac{\partial E}{\partial N}$$

you had written

$$\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial N}\right)_X=\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial E}\right)_X\left(\frac{\partial E}{\partial N}\right)_X,$$

where $X$ is the list of parameters to be held constant (and note that $X$ must be same for each term when you use the [chain rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule) in this way),
you would have seen that you cannot insert the substitutions

$$\frac{1}{T}\equiv\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial E}\right)_{V,N}$$

$$\mu\equiv\left(\frac{\partial E}{\partial N}\right)_{S,V}$$

because $V,N$ is different from $S,V$.

See also the [triple product rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_product_rule), which in this case is

$$\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial E}\right)_{V,N}\left(\frac{\partial E}{\partial N}\right)_{V,S}\left(\frac{\partial N}{\partial S}\right)_{V,E}=-1.$$

Comment: so if I am derivating entropy w.r.t the particle number while having E,V constant, then the same should apply to both of the other partial derivations? Which would lead in a zero, since the energy doesn't change and its derivation w.r.t the particle number is zero?

Comment: I’m not quite sure what you’re asking, but variables held constant in one derivative term aren’t necessarily constant in a different derivative term.

Comment: Then if they aren't necessarily constant what's the problem with V, N being different from S,V ?

Comment: Oh, I kinda get it. Since we are talking about micro canonical ensemble (N,V,E) we must only observe these quantities, whether they are constant or no, and in my above equation I took S into consideration, which is a mistake, correct?

Comment: When you use the [chain rule](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule) in the way you did, the constants must be the same (as I wrote with $X$ above). This isn’t necessarily the case with other identities, such as the triple product rule. I’ve updated my answer to note this.

Comment: It’s fine to hold S constant.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127128/discussion-between-imbaf-and-chemomechanics).